# drupal 7 on iis 7 403 and 404 pages not working remotely

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, drupal

Very new to IIS 7, so apologies if this is a simple one.

I've installed Drupal 7 using the Webstart installer on Windows Server 2008 R2. Drupal makes it's own custom 404 and 403 error pages. When I open up Internet Explorer on the server and test these, they work fine.

However, from a remote machine:

- Testing what should return a custom 404 page (that is the page doesn't exist), I get a blank page in Firefox, and IE shows a 403 "The website declined to show this webpage" when friendly error messages are turned on, and a blank page when they are turned off.
- Testing what should return a custom 403 page (by visiting the admin area with a non-authenticated user) returns a "Server Error. 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
  " in the IIS style.

I'm guessing this is a permissions problem, but I can't find anything to change.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Frederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with IIS web.config file for your site.

This article helped me overcome the issue: http://www.evanclosson.com/devlog/iis7httperrorsconfigurationonlockdown.

Have a read for this post on drupal groups: http://groups.drupal.org/node/25421

Otherwise you can use my config file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
  <!-- Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory. -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Protect files and directories from prying eyes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|test|po|sh|.sql|postinst.1|theme|tpl(.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style.pl|Entries.|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Access is forbidden." />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Force simple error message for requests for non-existent favicon.ico" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="favicon.ico" />
          <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="1" statusReason="File Not Found" statusDescription="The requested file favicon.ico was not found" />
        </rule>
        <!-- Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'. -->
        <rule name="Short URLS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
              <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/favicon.ico$" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?q={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <httpErrors>
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
      <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/index.php" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <defaultDocument>
      <!-- Set the default document -->
      <files>
        <remove value="index.php" />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Great! The solution was to add errorMode="Detailed" the httpErrors tag. Thanks!